# How To Upload Xml data into the skydrive server?

Tags: android, xml, cloud, onedrive

When the user enters the registration data it will be created and stored in xml file whenever a new user register  then it has to append the created xml file but my problem is that how to upload that `xml data file in skydrive rather than db or webservices` by which it has to be update when change is done and how can we read the data present in the skydrive xml file.

And I have one doubt regarding this

1. When the app opened for  the first time i didnot want to give the username and password 
   By default it has to be opened.Is it possible ?

Please provide me some sample example code it will be very helpful.

Comment: kindly look this png for upload xml http://sdrv.ms/16fv8NN

Answer (score 0):

you can also use share option here : look this : 
http://sdrv.ms/16fwwjq